# How to start loop from 1 after reaching a variabel assigned number

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I want to create a loop in php which start again from 1 after reaching a specific number assigned in variable.

1. Loop has to run 10 time
2. But after reaching 5 as i++ i want this loop to start again from 1 something as given below.

   1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5

Please help!!

Comment: `for inside while(true)`

Comment: Did you try to reset the loop variable back to 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
$i=1;
while($i<=10)
{
   echo $i;
   $i++;
   if($i>5)
   {
     $i=1;
     echo "</br>";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the modulo operator, `%`. This will cause numbers to "cycle" like what you want.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo ($i % 5) + 1;
}
```

The above will print out the numbers 1 through 5 twice.

Comment: This was helpful but still im unable to achieve my goal. I want to create a loop on date so if my search between two month like form 28-Jan-2015 to 04-Feb-2015 Loop should start over again for once reached the last date of Jan month (31) and also change the month to (02) Feb Something like this format (dd-mm) (28-01,29-01,30-01,31-01,01-02,02-02,03-02)

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
$count = 0;
for ($i = 1 ; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $count++;
    echo $count;
    if ($count == 5) {
       $count = 0;
       echo "</br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: If you will set $i=1 then it will incremented to 2 and then the loop will start with 2 and not 1

Comment: Still there are mistakes your code is returning
12345
2345
2

Comment: Can you debug it now??

Comment: Yes its returning the expected output now i have added br for a better view of output

Comment: I removed it please check the code before posting :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    $loop=1;
    for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
    {
       echo $loop;
       if($i==5)
       {
          $loop=0;
          echo "</br>";
       }
       $loop++;
    }
    ?>
```

**Output:**
12345
12345

---

This can be achieved without using loop also please find the below 2 functions helpful

**First:**

```
function createDateRangeArray($strDateFrom,$strDateTo)
{
    // takes two dates formatted as YYYY-MM-DD and creates an
    // inclusive array of the dates between the from and to dates.

    // could test validity of dates here but I'm already doing
    // that in the main script

    $aryRange=array();

    $iDateFrom=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateFrom,5,2),     substr($strDateFrom,8,2),substr($strDateFrom,0,4));
    $iDateTo=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateTo,5,2),     substr($strDateTo,8,2),substr($strDateTo,0,4));

    if ($iDateTo>=$iDateFrom)
    {
        array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom)); // first entry
        while ($iDateFrom<$iDateTo)
        {
            $iDateFrom+=86400; // add 24 hours
            array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom));
        }
    }
    return $aryRange;
}
```

**Second:**

```
    $st_date = '2012-07-20';
    $ed_date = '2012-07-27';
    $dates = range(strtotime($st_date), strtotime($ed_date),86400);
    $range_of_dates = array_map("toDate", $dates);
    print_r($range_of_dates);
    function toDate($x){return date('Y-m-d', $x);}
```

These 2 functions will be returning you the dates between the 2 dates you will pass and then you can loop on the output array to perform operations

Comment: This was helpful but still im unable to achieve my goal. I want to create a loop on date so if my search between two month like form 28-Jan-2015 to 04-Feb-2015 Loop should start over again for once reached the last date of Jan month (31) and also change the month to (02) Feb Something like this format (dd-mm) (28-01,29-01,30-01,31-01,01-02,02-02,03-02)

Comment: @PratikVerma I have updated the answer according to your comment

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:-**

```
$count = 10;
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{   
    if($i != ($count-1)){$coma = ',';}else{$coma = '';}
    $value = ($i % 5)+1;
    $output = $value.$coma;

    echo $output;
}
```

**Output:-** 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5

Comment: It can be achieved without the use of array and array function it is increasing unnecessary load